# Why WebSocketStompClient has connect but doesn't have disconnect method?

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

To connect to url(as client) in my code I have following code

```
@Autowired
private WebSocketStompClient client;

....

client.connect(wsUrl, handler);
```

usually if we have connect method we have disconnect method, start/stop and so on.

but `WebSocketStompClient` doesn't have disconnect method.

Should not I disconnect it after usage?